# update uitableview cell object

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiwebview

i have a tableview that contains a uiwebview in its first row. i would like to change this tables' webview object with new one when user clicks a button. i am using the code given below but it does not work fine. older object is there and the newer one is over it although i recreate the webview. how can i remove the older one from cell?

thanks...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSLog(@"NİL.......");
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
} else {
    NSLog(@"NOT NİL.......");
}

[cell addSubview:webView];  


return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier", your should reconfigure the cell each time when the cell is displayed.
Please remember that the cells with same identity will be reused. It's better to set the same identity to one particular type of cells, typically cells with same subviews and layout.

This is sample for how to load data and reconfigure a cell: http://code.google.com/p/tweetero/source/browse/trunk/Classes/MessageListController.m

Here is a tutorial to get familiar with UITableView:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html